# How do you code batch?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create a batch file, but I can't find a way to select the coding language. If it is not there, is there another program I can use to code something for a school project in batch?

Comment: "Batch" is its own language.

Comment: Assuming Windows Batch, they are written using BATCH commands and some simple control of flow constructs; you don't select a language.  Do you mean Windows Script?

Comment: notepad on windows or gedit on linux will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start>Programs>Accessories>Command Prompt and right-click; Send to desktop.

This will create a desktop "shortcut".

Right-click on the shortcut to set properties like text colour, size and font.

This will open what is commonly referred to as a "Dos session."

you can exit from that screen (It isn't DOS - it **emulates** DOS) by typing

```
QUIT
```

(and every command ends with the `enter` key (never shown)

Then just use a text-editor (Notepad at a pinch, I prefer [Editplus](https://www.editplus.com/) to create the programs.

Answer (score 0):

Just google "batch file programming tutorial" or something, I promise you will find something interesting. Go through this, for example: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/55203-batch-tutorial-part-1/ to get a basic understanding of batch and programming (although I wouldn't call batch programming; more likely to be called a scripting language).

(By the way, I find Notepad++ very good, but you don't need a special editor, as any text editor, for example Notepad.exe works fine, pre-installed with Windows.)